# dismiss UIVIew function from Superview within Custom View Class

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have a custom view, that has a button. I want this button to dismiss the view no matter where the view is created. I hope it makes sense.

```
@objc func dateSubmission(sender: CustomButton){
    sender.shake()
    let currentDate = Date()
    let interval = datepicked?.timeIntervalSince(currentDate)
    print(interval)
    let notifcation = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    notifcation.title = notificationTitle ?? "title empty"
    notifcation.subtitle = "test"
    notifcation.body = "test2"
    notifcation.badge = 1

    let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: interval!, repeats: false)
    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "taskReminder", content: notifcation, trigger: trigger)
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request, withCompletionHandler: nil)

}
```

I tried adding removefromsuperview() but it doesn't work.

Comment: What view are you trying to dismiss? Your code shows the setup for a local notification…

Comment: This is the button function that is located inside the view that should dismiss the view...

Comment: Nothing happens when you do `removeFromSuperview`?